What is the recommended way to apply sitecore Cumulative hotfix
I am referring to the blog  for adding cummulative hotfix.
My question : How to Ensure Correct DLLs During Debugging After Adding a Cummulative patch to Cummlative patch Project
If I add a new project to the solution and include the cumulative patch DLLs in it, does this guarantee that when I am debugging any feature like accordion, I am debugging it with the correct DLL?
Specifically:

Will the feature be compiled against the latest DLL provided in the
Sitecore cumulative patch?.
Does this approach ensure that the feature being debugged includes all updates from the cumulative patch?

I want to ensure that the debugging process reflects the actual functionality as per the latest cumulative patch, also ensuring that my projects are being complied the latest cummulative patch dll's .

could you add how is you project set up? TDS or Helix Publishing Pipeline or other?

@KamilC it's setup on Helix Publishing

As discussed in that article, I think the most important thing is to ensure is that the culmative hotfix is deployed on top of your solution. So if you are following the approach linked in that article, then the hotfixes project needs to be copied to your IIS directory as the last step (similarly when deploying to production).
Once you have those latest sitecore DLLs running in your local IIS sitecore website, you can attach to the W3W process and test out any functionality that you are working on - your custom code will then reference the latest DLLs. This will effectively allow you to debug your code runs successfully against hotfix dlls at runtime.
Generally speaking, I dont think you need to worry to much about ensuring your code compiles successfully against the culmative hotfix DLLs. Culmative hotfixes normally address security issues in the larger Sitecore platform. So its unlikely that any changes would be introduced to Sitecore API (classes and methods) that you would be consuming in your custom code.
Testing new features against hotfix DLLs at runtime should be sufficient. However, if you are determined to test against the latest DLLS, then I guess you would need to add the new DLLs to you solution in a library folder. Then update each individual reference across all projects. This would prove cumbesrsome however, as it would take you away from simple NUGET updates, which you would have to reimplement when you come to upgrade.

Since you are using Helix Publishing Pipeline, I would recommend following approach described in GitHub docs https://github.com/richardszalay/helix-publishing-pipeline.
First, ensure that all Sitecore Assemblies are excluded from publish artifact. Either by using Sitecore provided Assemblies List csv files (https://developers.sitecore.com/downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/104/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_104) or Sitecore Assemblies Nuget packages (https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/latest/sitecore-experience-manager/sitecore-assembly-list-nuget-packages.html#available-packages).
Next, when you have above sorted you can start adding files from Cumulative Hotfix to your Hotfix project. Ensure that each dll have Build Action set as None and Copy to Output Directory as Copy Always to get them in output artifact bin folder.
Finally, in your root project where HPP is installed, add reference to Hotfix project and in ProjectName.wpp.targets include these assemblies. Like below example:
<!--Exclude Assemblies below -->
<ItemGroup>
  <SitecoreAssembliesToExclude Include="@(SitecoreAssemblies)" />
  <SitecoreAssemblyListsToExclude Include="AssemblyLists\*.csv" />
<ItemGroup> 

<!--Hotfix Assemblies below added indvidually or use GitHub example to wrap them in SitecoreHotfixAssemblies node https://github.com/richardszalay/helix-publishing-pipeline?tab=readme-ov-file#excluding-sitecore-assemblies -->
<ItemGroup>
  <SitecoreAssembliesToInclude Include="Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.dll" />
  <SitecoreAssembliesToInclude Include="Sitecore.Analytics.Core.dll" />
<ItemGroup> 

For any web.config transforms you should use transforms like web.config.debug or .xdt equalivant, depending on your implementation.
This approach will work for Standalone, for CM and CD roles deployments to always have Hotfix files deployed on top of Sitecore. To verify correct assemblies/files are to be deployed you can always check CI build artifact or locally in your root VS project obj/Debug/Package/PackageTmp folder.
